# How to prevent a try-with-resources from closing a BufferedReader from lines() (Stream<String>)?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, autocloseable

This is what I am doing to prevent a `BufferedReader` from being closed when `lines()` finishes in a `try-with-resources`:

This is a general utility and it operates on a whole lot of Readers, not just Files ..

```
public static List<String> getLines(Reader reader, boolean trim, boolean closeReader) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(reader);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader) {

            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                if (closeReader) {
                    super.close();
                }
            }

        };

        try (Stream<String> lines = br.lines()) {
            return lines.map(it -> trim ? it.trim() : it)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
    }
```

Is there any better way of controlling so that the closing of `Stream<String>` does not also close the `Bufferedreader`?

As per the comments below to try a normal `try`, it would look like this:

```
public static List<String> getLines(Reader reader, boolean trim, boolean closeReader) throws IOException {
    Objects.requireNonNull(reader);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

    try {
        return br.lines()
                .map(it -> trim ? it.trim() : it)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } finally {
        if (closeReader) {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

That seems better :)

Comment: Don't use a try-with resources; use a normal try.

Comment: I think the best bet is to not use a try with resources, but have you verified the value of closeReader.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that what you describe is possible. Your try-with-resources is just closing the `lines`, *not* `br`. It is `lines` itself that is closing `br`; and there's no way to close `lines` without closing `br`.

What's more, I don't understand why you would *want* to avoid closing `br`. You are reading all the way to the end of the reader (by performing `collect`); what's the point of keeping it open after that?

Comment: I agree. However, I *thought* I had some methods somewhere where the reader (a custom reader) still needs to be open. I'll have to search to find where ... Looks like I can get rid of the close parameter! But it is still a good question to understand what happens with autocloseable and how to work around it :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to close a Stream, unless you need to close an underlying resource.

Most Streams (such as those pointing to in-memory collections) don't need closing at all.

**MOREOVER**, the Stream returned by `BufferedReader.lines()` will not close the BufferedReader if closed! (in b119) Use `Files.lines()` instead.